# ClassNotFound exception in java command

Tags: java, noclassdeffounderror, classnotfoundexception

I have simple Hello word program. Program will compile and run when not declare namespace in code but when I declared the class within namespace and compile the program it will complie successfully but it will given an error classnotfound when this program run. My question is why java complier not availble to find class when declare namespace (package) in code?

**Please find below source code:**

```
package org;

public class Chunk
{

   public static void main(String [] args)
   {
    System.out.println("Hello, World");
   }
}
```

**and command is**

```
java org.Chunk
```

**and error is**

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/Chunk
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.Chunk
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
Could not find the main class: org.Chunk.  Program will exit.
Exception in thread "main"
```

Comment: from where you r running it? try running it from parent of 'org' folder.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting this error probably because the class is not part of the classpath. You can specify a classpath using `-cp` java option, to point to the directory/jar where the org.Chunk  class is found.

Comment: He's probably just trying to run it from the wrong parent folder.

Comment: @NilsH Yes that was my filling also. Using `-cp` and specifying the proper directory, will allow him to run the test from any location.

Comment: Yes I am running command from wrong location. Now I am changed my parent dic and problem solved. But I have similar problem when run java -cp mytest.jar classname command. Can u help me why this command raise class not found error

Comment: @JagdishTalele You can check using `jar tvf mytest.jar` to see if `org/Chunk.class` is pressent in the archive.

Comment: @dan Yes it is there but still its gives the ClassNotfound error.

Comment: @JagdishTalele If the `org/Chunk.class` is present in the jar file, then executing with: `jar -cp mytest.jar org.Chunk` should work. If it's not working please provide the output of `jar tvf mytest.jar`

Comment: @dan Thanks for your help : I got the problem, I am using "ant dist" command to build the JAR file. I think in that manifest file having the problem hence I moved to JAR command and now its work fine for me.